# SQL Server management hangs when I have snapshot isolation in code

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, isolation-level

I have set my database snapshot_isolation_state_desc = ON

In c# when I start a new transaction

```
var dbTransaction = _myContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);
```

// delete

--- break point

//insert

on the break point when I go to sql management studio and query a table it hangs until i complete the transaction. I would like to be able to see the data in the table not just hang.. But I also want to complete my c# transaction. Am I using the wrong Isolation level?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Am I using the wrong Isolation level?

Yes. The default isolation level in SSMS is `READ_COMMITTED` so writers (the app code) will block readers (SSMS query) unless you've turned on the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option. Each session can run in different isolation level and the behavior of each will depend on the chosen level of that session.

Set the desired isolation level in the SSMS query window prior to querying the table so that your query is not blocked by the uncommitted change made by the app code:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;
```